# Uniqueness Validation on has_many association records via accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here are my **Models**:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities_users, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :cities, through: :cities_users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cities_users
end


class CitiesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city

  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :city_id, message: "already specified that they have lived in this city"}
end


class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities_users
  has_many :users, through: :cities_users
end
```

While creating a new `user` record: The user can dynamically add cities that they have lived in (via the [nested_form_fields](https://rubygems.org/gems/nested_form_fields) gem ). This ultimately creates records on the join table of `cities_users`.

[image: clicking button]

**After clicking the 'Add a city you have lived in' button:**

[image]

**User then goes and clicks the button again to add another city:**

[image: click button again]

That situation above is where I want a validation error to trigger when the user clicks the `Create User` button.  When creating a new user record: a user should NOT specify that they lived in the same city more than one time.

So above: without a validation: **two** `cities_users` records would be created with the same `user_id` and `city_id`.  This is no good, so I want to re-render the form, highlight the two offending `cities_users` nested_fields and have an error message say something like "You cannot specify that the user has lived in the same city more than once".

Clearly this requires a validation either on the `user` model or the `cities_user` model.  I do not know where the validation should go, and I do not know how to code the validation so that it catches this error.  The current `uniqueness` validation I have on the `CitiesUser` model does not catch this situation.

**Extra setup information just in case someone wants to recreate the scenario**

This was how I set up the nested_fields within the user `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= f.nested_fields_for :cities_users do |ff| %>

<div>
  <%= ff.label :city_id %>
  <%= ff.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>

<% end %>

<br>

<div><%= f.add_nested_fields_link :cities_users, "Add a City You have lived in" %></div>
```

The `users_controller#create` action is standard, generated from the `scaffold` command.  I did add to the strong params in order to allow for the nested attributes:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, cities_users_attributes: [:id, :city_id, :user_id])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to do the job:

```
#models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :cities_users
  has_many :cities, through: :cities_users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cities_users, allow_destroy: true

  validate :no_duplicate_cities

  private

  def no_duplicate_cities
    errors.add(:duplicate_cities, "are present") if self.cities_users.group_by(&:city_id).values.detect{|arr| arr.size > 1}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do in my opinion since you are passing this to the User model in your user_params method is to add a custom validation in your User model.  Force the id of the city they're adding to be unique in the array of cities being submitted via 'id'.  Do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :no_duplicate_cities

  #I'm assuming user_cities is an array of city id's so we only want one id of each different city at most.
  def no_duplicate_cities
    self.user_cities = self.user_cities.uniq
  end
```

This will only leave the unique id's in that array removing any duplicate cities.

Comment: thank you for your answer. this answer is close but as is doesn't work. `self.users_cities` returns a collection proxy object.  What I did is I created the `no_duplicate_cities` private method, put a breakpoint in there, called `self.users_cities` to see what it would give me back.  Here is an example: `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<UsersCity id: nil, user_id: nil, city_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<UsersCity id: nil, user_id: nil, city_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<UsersCity id: nil, user_id: nil, city_id: 3, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>`

Comment: perhaps somehow I need to iterate through the items within the collection_proxy, see if an item with that `city_id` already exists in the list, and if so reject it?

Comment: I had hopes that this would do it, but it isn't.  any suggestions? `self.users_cities = self.users_cities.uniq{|user_city| user_city.city_id}`

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar within an app of mine, try the below code in your User model.

```
validate :unique_cities

def unique_cities
  unless self.user_cities.map(&:city_id).uniq
    errors.add(:cites, "- can not be 2 of the same cities")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Dave.  Unfortunately the `uniq` method isn't doing what we would like for it to here.

Comment: oh i see your response! good work, looks like you got on the right track